# Vert.x : How can i catch exception in handler onSuccess?

Tags: vert.x

Here is my code:

```
    private static void testExceptionInHandle() {
        try {
            var handler = future().onSuccess(v -> {
                throw new RuntimeException("hello exception");
            }).onFailure(e -> {
                System.out.println("onFailure:" + e.getMessage());
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("catch:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I wonder what happened with an unpredictable exception but get nothing.

This causes the route processing method to not end properly.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of runtime issues normally bubble up to the exception handler of the Vert.x context or of Vert.x itself (by default, it simply logs the exception).

To make sure the routing process finishes, you should setup a `TimeoutHandler` on your routes.

Otherwise, you can try using another programming model like Mutiny or RxJava. Any runtime exception will be reported to the subscriber (and then of course terminate the subscription).

Answer (score 0):

You can define failureHandler on your route and catch all runtime exeptions. More details: https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/Route.html#failureHandler-io.vertx.core.Handler-